# How does the template deduction and decltype(T) works on a refrence?

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I am learning template in C++. Something I don't understand is that:
Given a type `X`, and create an object `X a;`, if I define a reference to `a` by `X& b = a;`, then `std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value` returns true. However, is I take b as an argument to a template function, the deducted type is not a reference.

```
#include <iostream>

class X {};

template<typename T>
void
F(T t)
{
    if (std::is_reference<T>::value)
        std::cout << "T is a reference" << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
    X a;
    X &b = a;
    std::cout << std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value << std::endl; // return true
    F(b); //return false
}
```

My question is why the code works like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `b` **as an expression** is `X` due to [[expr.type]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

So `T` is deduced to be `X`. However `decltype(b)` is not simply the type of `b` as an expression. According to [[dcl.type.simple]/4](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4) (irrelevant part is elided by me):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - ...
> - otherwise, if e is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of **the entity named by `e`**. ...
> - ...

Note it's the type of the entity named by `b` (i.e. `X&`), not the type of the expression `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer the "why"-part of the question: The function

```
void someFunc(int arg) { /* ... */ }
```

clearly receives its argument by value. Having the `int` in mind, what kind of semantics do you expect from this function?

```
template<class T> void someFunc(T arg) { /* ... */ }
```

I would expect the argument to be passed by value, too. Now consider the calling snippets, in the first case

```
int i;
int& j = i;

someFunc(j); /* j passed by value. */
```

and in the second case

```
X a;
X& b = a;

someFunc(b); /* b passed by reference? Luckily not. */
```

With the function template signature instead being

```
template<class T> someFunc(T& arg) { /* ... */ }
```

there is not much potential missunderstanding at the point of invocation - the argument is passed by reference. In the end, this boils down to integers being *regular types*, while references aren't (see [this post](https://abseil.io/blog/20180531-regular-types) for a recent treatise, also covering pointers).